# How to approve in code for XCTest unit tests requesting user location

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, xctest

I have a unit(integration) test that calls a func in view controller to a live API only if user has given location permission. This is my logic to check if user gave the authorization or not.

`[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`

This works fine in normal code since user can tap/select 1. "Allow Once" or 2. "Allow while using the app"

But my question is how can I set either of these options in unit test since tests they will need to run on Jenkins later.

Note, I have this in my info.plist for the actual app target but not the test target.

`<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>`

`<string>${ALWAYS_LOCATION_DESCRIPTION}</string>`

Comment: Testing behaviour in "life" UIViewControllers in _Unit Tests_ is difficult at best. And unit tests are not meant to test integration. Luckily, that's not your only option. First, you need to separate your logic out from the view controller. Then, use a "CLLocationManager Mock" which simulates the real external dependency, but is under full control in your unit test setup. Then, for any state in your location manager mock, test your logic. For _Integration Test_, you may use UI Tests. This topic is more complex. Even then, you may not want to use a "life" service, but instead a "mock", too.

Comment: Please refine your question to narrow it down to where a concrete answer is possible. ;)